# Why is my local REDCap instance's module only displaying a directory listing instead of loading the page?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, redcap

I have been working on a test REDCap installation on my local machine before my team sets up a production server. The laptop provided by my organization is running Windows 11 Pro, which I'm admittedly rusty with, but have getting mostly up to speed.

The current status of my installation makes all configuration checks pass on green. I am also able to install external modules and configure them, however once I click the actual module link the only thing that displays is a clickable file directory at that location.

[Configured but not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kxz1.png)

The first picture (above) shows configuration ability next to the incorrectly loading module. The second picture (below) shows that it's listed normally in the sidebar and clickable.

[The installed module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmvmk.png)

MySQL and REDCap are the newest versions, except PHP, which is 8.1. After running a [containerized instance](https://github.com/123andy/redcap-docker-compose) of REDCap, it seems that versions are not conflicting as the modules both display properly. I was able to install it with the same exact method and it correctly displayed.

[Correctly displaying module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRsxt.png)

Though I followed the instructions for the installation procedure, I feel that something is incorrectly set up... and have been trying to focus on how it's configured in Apache specifically. I was thinking that it could be where the directory is saved, but everything else seems to run normally.

The current path is `C:\Apache24\htdocs\redcap\redcap_v13.10.0\home.php` which resolves to `https://local.host/redcap/redcap_v13.10.0/home.php` - I was thinking the path may be some part of the issue, but I'm stumped.

I initially tried downgrading REDCap to 13.7.x LTS, then tried downgrading PHP to version 7.4.x as I thought maybe the modules were not loading due to compatibility issues.

I have attempted to install the module manually (downloading the module and pasting it directly into the module directory), as I thought the simpler "click to install" feature may have been at fault (it wasn't).

I have checked the Apache configuration file for possible oversights (such as ensuring `DirectoryIndex` includes `index.html` and `index.php`, as well as the checking `php.ini` but I didn't personally catch anything that was off. This is the angle I am currently working, as I think there may be some additional configuration with virtual hosts in Apache that I am unaware of- but I'm a bit new to Apache as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar issue, I am answering my own question as I found the answer.

It turns out that my Apache server was configured incorrectly. Here is the correct configuration, which you add at the end of your `httpd.conf` file:

```
# PHP8 Configuration
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php_module "C:\php\php-8-1\php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:\php\php-8-1"
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

`LoadModule` is the full path to the `.dll` stored in your php directory, wherever that may be.

`PHPIniDir` is the root of that dir, where your `php.ini` file is found.